# HTML VBA code from excel to outlook populate To:

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, sendmail

I have the following code which is activated by a button in an excel work book.
The button extracts information required and transfers to a table in Outlook. However I can't work out how to code column M (containers an email address) from excel to the '**To**' field of my email.

```
Sub Email()

    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 15 '<< the row with column headers
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 8   '<< how many columns of data

    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Dim ol As Object, fldr, ns, msg
    Dim html As String, c As Range, colReq As Long, hdr As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ol = GetObject(, "outlook.application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ol = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        fldr.Display
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't start Outlook to compose mail!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set msg = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set rw = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow
msg.To = ""
    msg.Subject = "Hapag Lloyd UK Haulage Issue Alert"

    html = "<style type='text/css'>"
    html = html & "body, p {font:10pt calibri;padding:40px;}"
    html = html & "table {border-collapse:collapse}"
    html = html & "td {border:1px solid #000;padding:4px;}"
    html = html & "</style>"

    html = html & "<p>Dear Sir / Madam,"
    html = html & "<p>Please see below reported transport issue:</p>"
    html = html & "<table>"



    For Each c In rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Cells
        If c.Column <> 10 Then '<<< EDIT to exclude ColD
            Set hdr = rw.Parent.Cells(HEADER_ROW, c.Column) '<< get the header text for this cell

            html = html & "<tr><td style='background-color:#DDD;width:200px;'>" & _
               hdr.Text & _
               "</td><td style='width:400px;'>" & Trim(c.Text) & "</td></tr>"
        End If 'we want this cell
    Next c

    html = html & "</table>"
html = html & "<p>If an ETA is not shown above please revert with your latest acceptance within 30 minutes of this email. </p>"
html = html & "<p>Kind Regards, </p>"
html = html & "<p>Hapag Lloyd UK Haulage Alert Team."
html = html & "<p>Late.Run@hlag.com </p>"
html = html & "<p>0208-507-4000 > Option 4 </p>"
    msg.htmlbody = html
    msg.Display
    Email_To = "ActiveSheet.Range M16"


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Something like `msg.To = ActiveSheet.Range("M16")`? I'm not sure why you originally have `msg.To = ""` or what you're trying to do with `Email_To = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get a well-formed html markup with `<body>` tags and etc. Only then you can assign it to the `HTMLBody` property of the mail item class.

There are two main ways for setting the To field:

1. Using the `To` property.

   ```
   msg.To = ActiveSheet.Range("M16")
   ```
2. Using the `Recipients.Add` method.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, such a simple answer ! Column M always contains the email address for the issue in the same row - therefore how do I request that the macro looks in column M when button pressed on row 17 (ie M17 / M18 etc....) Thank you

Comment: Can anybody help with the above please ?